# React app with wordrpess on nginx won't work on HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

I'm building a React app with a wordpress site on it.
It should work on this way:

example.com -> Takes me to my react app
example.com/blog -> Takes me to my wordpress blog.

I have an EC2 running with nginx using a reverse proxy to redirect users to my wordpress blog. And my config is this:

```
  listen 80;
  listen 443 http2 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/react-app/react-app/build;
  index index.html;

  access_log off;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/react-app.error.log;

  location ^~/blog {
   proxy_pass https://54.175.178.245;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }


  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {

     expires 365d;

  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    alias /var/www/react-app/react-app/build/favicon.ico;
  }

}
```

The issue I have is that it works correctly when I use my server's IP, but it does not work when I go to example.com

It just won't redirect me to my wordpress app.

It is important to mention that if I enter directly to example.com/blog on incognito mode, it does work correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Okay, so in fact these two lines are not needed:

```
listen 443 http2 ssl;
listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
```

I am managing my SSL certificates through an ELB on AWS, which is connected with my EC2 server.

Right now my server config appears to work, since it works correctly if I use cURL.
If I request example.com/blog from cURL, it works correctly. But it does not work correctly on my browser.

Comment: so if it work with CURL, that mean you got cache issues with your browser, you should try with another computer

Comment: I have tried with several devices and got the same result in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix 80 and 443 on the same block specially if your want to reverse proxy https

```
{
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name *.example.com;

    root /var/www/react-app/react-app/build;
    index index.html;

    ssl_...
    ...

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/react-app.error.log;

    location /blog/ { # the end trailing slash is important
        proxy_pass https://54.175.178.245/blog;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

     location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
       expires 365d;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
      alias /var/www/react-app/react-app/build/favicon.ico;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so in fact these two lines are not needed:

```listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
```
I am managing my SSL certificates through an ELB on AWS, which is connected with my EC2 server.

Comment: can you confirm that your load balancer see minimum one app, look somewhere on healcheck to see 1/1 and not 0/1

Comment: This is what healthcheck looks like:


```172.31.7.147 - - [24/Feb/2020:06:25:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 393 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"```